# Run Get-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto via Azure app

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to run Get-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto via an automated script, I connect using:

```
Connect-azuread -CertificateThumbPrint "xxx" -ApplicationId "xxx" -tenantid "xxx"
```

This is an Azure AD app with permission 'User.ReadWrite.All'.

When I run the command I get access denied:

```
PS C:\scripts> Get-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto -ObjectId joe.soap@domain.com
Get-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto : Error occurred while executing GetAzureADUserThumbnailPhoto
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
```

I can't find any reference to what permission is needed and I can't test various different app permissions because I'm not the cloud admin. I'm not sure if this is even possible via an app.

I'm also not interested in using Get Photo using MS Graph, as this returns different results.

Answer (score 1):

The error due to user has **no admin** privileges,

And also Add the `User.Read.All`, and  `User.ReadWrite.All` permissions

try with using  the powershell to get the user's ThumbnailPhoto.

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto -ObjectId '85a293bb-xxxx-448b-xxxx-c927991c26a2' -FileName test -FilePath 'd:\adtest
```

After that, user's photo will store to **D:\adtest**, and it's **name is test**.

More information about this command, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduserthumbnailphoto?view=azureadps-2.0).

OR
`Get-UserPhoto` if you are using **Exchange Online**.

Comment: It states clearly that I gave the permission User.ReadWrite.All.